# Chrome extension with no icon?

Tags: google-chrome, icons, manifest

I am trying to create a simple Google Chrome extension. I don't want it to have an icon next to the omnibar. Is this possible? What do I need to put in my manifest.json?

Comment: Could you perhaps set the icon to a completely transparent png as a workaround? I know it's not a fix, but this isn't really the type of thing you need an extensible solution for...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. To do it, just don't declare `browser_action` in your manifest. Remember, though, to get it to work, you'll need to do something to run the script. `contextMenus` are a great way to do that.

Here's a manifest that has no browser action line, so it will not display an icon:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Example",

    "name":"Example",
    "icons": {
        "16": "img16.png" }, // Needed for the context menu

    "background": {
        "scripts":["background.js"] },

    "permissions":[ "tabs", "contextMenus" ], // contextMenus permission allows you to create the action
    "version": "1.0"
}
```